# Java's keyword "interface" not highlighted properly

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

[The `interface` keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) is not being highlighted. Even though the code block is recognized to be Java, the `interface` keyword is marked up by Prettify to be a plaintext.

```java
public interface YUNoHighlightMe {
    void someMethod();
}
```

Examples from SO:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/11279236/1273080
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9802513/1273080
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9802555/1273080
- [Java - Interface, instantiating an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10201081/1273080)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540929/1273080

---

**Edit:**

After a comment suggesting to test it out locally with Prettify, I did. The code used [(+ latest downloadable Prettify)](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/downloads/list):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="prettify.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="prettyPrint()">
        <pre class="prettyprint lang-java">public interface YUNoHighlightMe {
    void someMethod();
}</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

This **confirms the Prettify bug** as it does not highlight the keyword.

The interesting part is that if I omit the `lang-java` language hint, it works well and the word gets highlighted.

Comment: `throw new NamingConventionViolationException("yUNoHighlightMe");`

Comment: You seem to realize that the syntax highlighting is handled by Prettify; why are you filing this here? File it against [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/list)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Oh, right. I kinda thought SE was using it's own version or maybe some other inner mechanism was interfering with it. Those assumptions... I'll file it and post it here as an answer ASAP.

Comment: @slanec you're right there, sometimes MarkDown _does_ interfere with prettify and mathjax. In that case, first test it out in a pure prettify environment and then determine where the bug is to be filed.

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles Now that's what I wanted to hear. The local test confirmed the bug, details in the updated question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bug has been filed on the Prettify project:

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=225

---

**EDIT** (Feb 2013): Fixed at the Prettify side.

Comment: _"The interesting part is that if I omit the "lang-java" language hint, it works well and the word gets highlighted."_ I guess this way Prettify authors try to communicate their belief that in Java, interfaces are designed the wrong way :)